# Area controllers are being called from root request

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-areas

I have some area in my ASP.NET MVC3 Application:

```
namespace MyProject.Areas.myarea
{
    public class myareaAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
    {
        public override string AreaName
        {
            get
            {
                return "myarea";
            }
        }

        public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
        {
            context.MapRoute(
                "myarea_default",
                "myarea/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

this area contains "Hello" controller with "Smile" action.

In global.asax file for whole project I have:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", 
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

    }

    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
```

So, when I request "localhost/myarea/hello/smile" it calls appropriate controller as expected.

BUT! When I request "localhost/hello/smile" it calls hello controller STILL! With that, it looks for the Views not in the myarea/Views folder, but in a ~/Views folder for "root" (non-area) level of project.

How can I fix this, so server will throw an 404 exception, that resource is not found, just like I requested non-existing controller?

**UPD:** Controllers in area are in namespace:

```
namespace MyProject.Areas.myarea.Controllers
{
    public class HelloController : Controller

...
}
```

Controllers in "root"-level are in namespace:

```
namespace MyProject.Controllers
{
    public class AnotherRootController : Controller
...
}
```

So I tried this in global.asax:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", 
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, 
            new [] { "MyProject.Controllers" } //Namespace
        );

    }
```

I thought this would restrict this route to "root"-level controllers only, since they are in MyProject.Controllers namespace. That DID NOT work. Area-controllers are still being called with request without areaname in it.

May be someone can explain, why?

Comment: In MVC4 "Default" route declaraton moved from Global.asax to ~/App_Start/RouteConfig.cs/RegisterRoutes()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could set the `UseNamespaceFallback=false` datatoken when registering the default route in your Global.asax by restricting it to look only for controllers in the given namespace. You may take a look at the [following blog post](http://suhair.in/Blog/Aspnet-MVC-Areas-in-depth-Part-2).

So to put that into action add a namespace restriction to your area registration:

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
{
    context.MapRoute(
        "myarea_default",
        "myarea/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
        new[] { "MyProject.Areas.myarea.Controllers" }
    );
}
```

and in your `Global.asax` set the UseNamespaceFallback data token to false when registering the default route in order to constrain it to the given namespace:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default",
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
        new[] { "MyProject.Controllers" }
    ).DataTokens["UseNamespaceFallback"] = false;
}
```

Comment: This also helped me solve an issue where registering the default route  where I wanted it to look in the given area for Views. (area token is not registered when using the default route). Using the DataTokens accessor to set the value of the "area" worked like a charm. This has been deemed a bug by a number of commenters I have seen (even if the framework is not supposed to support this). So thanks Darin.